# Converting char * to uppercase segfaults

Tags: c, string, pointers, segmentation-fault

I have a simple program where I have a string I've written in externally (in the case of this snippit, it's user created). And I'm trying to capitalize certain parts of it.

I first strtoked it by a delimiter, and attempted to capitalize it using the toupper function, however I seem to be getting segfaults doing it. Running valgrind provides no error, except simply states that:

```
Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==10180==  Bad permissions for mapped region at address 0x4007B9
```

The code:

```
int main(void) {
    char * test;

    char * f;
    char * s;
    char * p;

    test = "first:second:third:fourth:";
    f = strtok(test,":");


    for(p = f; *p; *p = toupper(*p), p++); //segfaults

    printf("f is %s \n",f); //this should print "FIRST" as it should be capitalized

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `f = s = p = test = malloc(sizeof(char * ) * 10);` what is this?

Comment: Memory leak, incorrect memory size...too many ...

Comment: @SouravGhosh Wow!!! I didn't see that!!!! When I see `test = strtok(STRING_LITERAL, ...)` I immediately answered.

Comment: I thought mallocing char * was good practice?

Comment: You may need to read a good book to start with, no offence.

Comment: @iharob you're also right, OP is overwriting that anyway....

Comment: `malloc()` has nothing to do with good or bad practice. You need to read about dynamic memory allocation, and learn what string literals are. It looks like you know some other programming language?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `strtok()` on a string literal because it modifies it's argument, and you can't modify a string literal.

Nor can you modify it in this loop

```
for (p = f; *p; *p = toupper(*p), p++); //segfaults
```

You need an array or a dynamically allocated block of memory, both of which are writeable, with the array you can initialize using a string literal like this

```
char array[] = "This is a string literal, you are not allowed to modify it";
/* Now the arest of the code could work but ... */
```

You also need to check the return value of `strtok()` which is `NULL` when it doesn't find what you ask to find.

Using `malloc()` you can do this too

```
cosnt char *string_literal = "This is a sample string";
size_t length = strlen(string_literal);
char *buffer = malloc(length + 1);
if (buffer == NULL)
    return -1; // Allocation failure.
memcpy(buffer, string_literal, length + 1);
//                                      ^ copy the null terminator too
// Process your newly allocated copy here and,
free(buffer);
```

**NOTE**: About your original code with

```
f = s = p = test = malloc(sizeof(char * ) * 10);
```

`malloc()` is not used as a general initialization function, it's used to get a pointer to memory that you can use in the program, you can read/write from/to it. When you ask for memory with `malloc()` you ask for a specific (*usually exact*) ammount of bytes to be used in your program.

The returned pointer is then usable if it's not `NULL`, in case there is an error or the system has ran out of memory it will return `NULL`.

Your code has a major issue since all the pointers `f`, `s`, `p` and `test` point to the same memory address and also because you allocated an arbitrary size which might or not be the one you want/need.

When you `free(f)` and then go on and `free(s)`, you are freeing the same pointer twice and you actually was doing it more than that. Calling `free()` twice on the same poitner invokes undefined behavior.

Comment: Fie! Your rep passed me!  ;-)